# Can HTML ranges have their endpoint on non-leaf nodes in the middle of a div?

Tags: html, selection-api

I have the following div:

```
<div contenteditable=true>
  <p> Some content here<br></p>
  <p> Some <strong>formatted</strong> content here containing <i>italics</i><strong>then bold</strong></p>
</div>
```

Is there any way an HTML selection (resp. a range) selected by the user could start or end at the point *between* the two paragraphs? Or in the general case, when I have a node with some children, can a selection start or end between two leaves? Another example would be the following case, where `|` denotes the start/end of a selection: `</i>|<strong>`.

Comment: between your two `<p>` there is a text node, that can definitely be selected by the user (e.g when `white-space:pre`) for the `</i><strong>` that seems more dubious.